# Are the electric flux lines between the fixed nucleus and the moving free electrons in the wire cut when an electric current flows in that wire?

Tags: electric-current

According to the displacement current theory, An electric flux variation 
around the wire is "I" when an electric current in that wire is "I".

Please, check the following paper and equation (18)
 http://www.jpier.org/PIER/pier144/30.13111501.pdf

If then, what happens to the the electric flux lines between the fixed 
nucleus and the moving free electrons in the wire when an electric current
flows in that wire?

Comment: Free electrons are moving all the time. Within the context of solid state physics, I'm struggling to actually figure out what you mean by electric flux lines and electric current - Bloch functions and band structure extend throughout the crystal.

Comment: Wikipedia on PIER: The journal is abstracted and indexed by the Science Citation Index Expanded, Current Contents, Inspec, Scopus, and Compendex. It is also a member of CrossRef. According to the Journal Citation Reports, the journal had a 2011 impact factor of 5.298. However, it was not listed in 2012 because of "anomalous citation patterns resulting in a significant distortion of the Journal Impact Factor, so that the rank does not reflect the journal's citation performance in the literature".